# Create Database Tables Windows 8 Metro

Tags: c#, sqlite, microsoft-metro

If I am logged into Windows 8 as a non-admin, such as the guest account, will this database creation code fail? If so, how can I change it works with non-admin users:

```
protected List<Order> orders;
    string dbName;
    #region Constructors

    public RestaurantRepository()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected void Initialize()
    {

        dbName = "db_sqlite-net.db3";

        // check the database, if it doesn't exist, create it
        CheckAndCreateDatabase(dbName);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Database

    protected string GetDBPath()
    {
        string dbRootPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
        return Path.Combine(dbRootPath, "menufinderwin8.db");
    }

    // This method checks to see if the database exists, and if it doesn't, it creates
    // it and inserts some data
    protected void CheckAndCreateDatabase(string dbName)
    {
        // create a connection object. if the database doesn't exist, it will create 
        // a blank database
        SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(GetDBPath());
        conn.CreateTableAsync<Order>();
        conn.CreateTableAsync<Order>();
        conn.CreateTableAsync<OrderDetail>();
        conn.CreateTableAsync<Product>();
        conn.CreateTableAsync<Restaurant>();

        //using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(GetDBPath()))
        //{

            // create the tables
          //  db.CreateTable<Order>();
            //db.CreateTable<OrderDetail>();
            //db.CreateTable<Product>();
            //db.CreateTable<Restaurant>();
            // close the connection
            //db.Close();
        //}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as long as the app is installed for all users, it should have access to its own local directory. I don't think you'd be able to share the database between the users, but I don't think it'd fail.

Let me know how it turns out, I'm curious :)